# How to implement a nav drawer with fragments and different views in each fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-navigation

Take a look at the Fitbit application [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitbit.FitbitMobile). It has a navigation drawer and the Dashboard item is swipable (basically you can swipe from today to yesterday, to the day before, etc.). My question, how can this be done?

I've read that it's recommended to use the navigation drawer with fragemnts. So if Dashboard is a fragment, how can we swipe that fragment left and right to change views? Is each date just a different view?

[image: Navigation Drawer]
 [image: Dashboard contents]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

The Dashboard looks like it is part of a ViewPager, which lets you swipe left or right to switch views. The drawer is a standard implementation of DrawerLayout (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout).